# Searching multiple columns through traits in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

By checking out [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9f5BbiyrPs8) I'm implementing a search url in my `Laravel 5.4` application. I've implemented a trait in my model for example if I'm having Company model so in model I'm including my trait something like this:

```
class Company extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes, DataViewer;

    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'address', 'city', 'state', 'country', 'type', 'sub_type',
    ];

    public static $columns = [
        'name', 'address', 'city', 'type', 'sub_type'
    ];
}
```

Now I'm having this `DataViewer` trait something like this:

```
trait DataViewer {

    protected $operators = [
        'equal' => '=',
        'not_equal' => '<>',
        'less_than' => '<',
        'greater_than' => '>',
        'less_than_or_equal_to' => '<=',
        'greater_than_or_equal_to' => '>=',
        'in' => 'IN',
        'like' => 'LIKE'
    ];

    public function scopeSearchPaginateAndOrder($query)
    {
        $request = app()->make('request');

        return $query
            ->orderBy($request->column, $request->direction)
            ->where(function($query) use ($request) {
                if($request->has('search_input')) {
                    if($request->search_operator == 'in') {
                        $query->whereIn($request->search_column, explode(',', $request->search_input));
                    } else if($request->search_operator == 'like') {
                        $query->where($request->search_column, 'LIKE', '%'.$request->search_input.'%');
                    }
                    else {
                        $query->where($request->search_column, $this->operators[$request->search_operator], $request->search_input);
                    }
                }
            })
            ->paginate($request->per_page);
    }

}
```

And I'm calling this in controller something like this:

```
public function getData()
{
    $models = Company::searchPaginateAndOrder();
    return response()->json([
        'model' => $models
    ]);
}
```

And to achieve this I'm calling url something like this:

```
http://stellar.dev/api/companies?column=name&direction=asc&page=1&per_page=50&search_column=name&search_operator=like&search_input=icici
```

The problem which I'm facing here is that it can search can only through one column, I want to have search with multiple columns in one query. Suggest me what can be done.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make your query string as an array for multiple columns like this.

```
http://stellar.dev/api/companies?column=name&direction=asc&page=1&per_page=50&search_column[]=name&search_operator[]=like&search_input[]=icici&search_column[]=lastname&search_operator[]=like&search_input[]=asd
```

Then read and use them as an array. Also you need to check their length to prevent unexpected errors. Then you can simple use a simple loop to concatenate your conditions like the following code block.

```
trait DataViewer {

    protected $operators = [
        'equal' => '=',
        'not_equal' => '<>',
        'less_than' => '<',
        'greater_than' => '>',
        'less_than_or_equal_to' => '<=',
        'greater_than_or_equal_to' => '>=',
        'in' => 'IN',
        'like' => 'LIKE'
    ];

    public function scopeSearchPaginateAndOrder($query)
    {
        $request = app()->make('request');
        $searchInputs = $request->get('search_input', []);
        $searchOperators = $request->get('search_operator', []);
        $searchColumns = $request->get('search_column', []);

        $query->orderBy($request->column, $request->direction);

        if(count($searchInputs) == count($searchOperators) && count($searchOperators) == count($searchColumns)) {
            $query->where(function($query) use ($searchInputs, $searchOperators, $searchColumns) {
                for($x = 0, $l = count($searchColumns); $x < $l; $x++){
                    if($searchOperators[$x] == 'in') {
                       $query->whereIn($searchColumns[$x], explode(',', $searchInputs[$x]));
                   } else if($searchOperators[$x] == 'like') {
                        $query->where($searchColumns[$x], 'LIKE', "%{$searchInputs[$x]}%");
                   }
                    else {
                       $query->where($searchColumns[$x], $searchColumns, $searchInputs[$x]);
                   }
               }
           });
        }

        return $query->paginate($request->per_page);
    }

}
```

Note: I strongly recommend use post verb for this search page or your data will be html encoded and your url is absolutely not user friendly.

**Edited Answer**

I have changed the code for multiple columns, single operator and single field.

```
public function scopeSearchPaginateAndOrder($query)
    {
        $request = app()->make('request');
        $searchInput = $request->get('search_input');
        $searchOperator = $request->get('search_operator');
        $searchColumns = $request->get('search_column', []);

        $query->orderBy($request->column, $request->direction);

        if(count($searchColumns) > 0) {
            $query->where(function($query) use ($searchInput, $searchOperator, $searchColumns) {
                for($x = 0, $l = count($searchColumns); $x < $l; $x++){
                    if($searchOperator == 'in') {
                        $query->whereIn($searchColumns[$x], explode(',', $searchInput));
                    } else if($searchOperator == 'like') {
                        $query->where($searchColumns[$x], 'LIKE', "%{$searchInput}%");
                    }
                    else {
                        $query->where($searchColumns[$x], $searchOperator, $searchInput);
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        return $query->paginate($request->per_page);
    }
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, I don't want a multiple input search or multiple  operators search, I just wanted to have multiple search_columns. And you were right, we must have all these data in post method.

Comment: this answer includes only multiple search columns. Just need to change waiting three array to waiting one array (search_columns). I have edited my answer and I hope it works.

Comment: Yes. Even I made those changes. Thanks..:)